# How can I get these formulas to work in C++?

Tags: c++

I develop in C++ in Visual Studio. I am trying to get this calculation to work for these three separate problems:

```
3.0 * 5.0  
7.1 * 8.3 - 2.2  
3.2 / (6.1 * 5)
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    double A = 3.0;
    double B = 5.0;
    double C = 7.0;
    double D = 8.3;
    double E = 2.2;
    double F = 3.2;
    double G = 6.1;
    double H = 5;
    double I 
    double J
    double K
    printf("")
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the answers to appear for these three problems? Do I just put the correct letters in parenthesis? What is the format?

Comment: first try to learn basics of c++,then it would be easy for you perform activities like these

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print

```
printf("%g",A*B);
printf("%g",C*D-E);
printf("%g",F/(G*H));
```

If you want to save in a new variable and print

```
I = A*B;
printf("%g",I);
```

and so on...

Comment: `%d`?  I think you mean `%g`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Im a C++ guy. corrected it

Answer (score 0):

you can print a double using

```
printf("%f", aDoubleOrSinglePrecisionFloat);
```

%lf is also valid .
you can also specify an output precision using %0.2f for example. it means you want only 2 decimal.

for the computation. use your letters/variables or directly the formula it doesn't matter.